# Excel VBA - setting series name in Pivot Graph

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to set a new name for a series in Excel VBA (Microsoft 365 version) for a Pivot Graph. However, this does not work as expected. In the simplified code below, I expect that the MsgBox will display "NewSeriesName", but it displays the old name.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graph_1").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "NewSeriesName"
    MsgBox (ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name)
    ActiveChart.Deselect
End Sub
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong and what a possible solution might be?

Comment: Your code works just as intended for me. https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5dt5.png

Comment: Works for me as well. Does the chart on the sheet get updated correctly with the "NewSeriesName"?

Comment: I get the same issue as you, so the problem could be how you created the chart or the kind of chart. I will dig further but @Andreas could you share the steps you took for the OP

Comment: Thanks for checking everyone.
@- kevin, the chart on the sheet does not show the new name. 

@CHill60, glad that I'm not the only one. It's a Pivot Chart if that's relevant.

Comment: Ok - if I put the chart on the same sheet as the data I don't get the problem. When I inserted a pivot chart Excel created a new sheet (with the pivoted data) and placed the Chart on that - so we're getting somewhere (I'm just not sure where)

Comment: At least we got a lead! But I did have the Pivot Table on the same page as the Pivot Chart. Now I put the table from which the Pivot Chart pulls the data also on the same page, but it still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @CHill60 I just took some data I had pasted on a sheet and clicked on the line chart button, then because I have a Swedish version of Excel I had to rename the chart to Graph_1. That is all I did. But everything that involves charts is a major pain in VBA

Comment: Very relevant that it's a pivot chart - you probably need to change the name in the pivot table, not the pivot chart. You could also update your question with a screenshot of what you are trying to change.